# MySQL: Getting connected (similar) data with lef/right fields

Tags: sql, mysql, database, relational-database

In MySQL Im having two tables:

- PRODUCTS (id, Name)
- SEEALSO (id, prodLeft, prodRight)

SEEALSO defines which PRODUCTS are related together and are represented as binded fileds "prodLeft"-"prodRight".
  For Example:

PRODUCTS:

- 1 Desk
- 2 Table
- 3 Chair
- 4 Doors
- 5 Tree
- 6 Flower

SEEALSO

- 1 1 2
- 2 2 3
- 3 3 4
- 4 5 6

From that we can see binding of **Desk-Table-Chair-Doors** and **Tree-Flower**.
I would now want to write SQL statement where I could specifie PRODUCT name (e.g. **Chair**) and i would get result of binded fields that are connected with it (e.g. **Chair: Desk-Table-Chair-Doors**).
From this point on i would like to know if this is even possible for my data presentation concept in SEEALSO and if it is if you could help me solve my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you're wondering whether it's even possible, you could look into [this information on Nested Sets](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/), which is the MySQL way of doing this (I gather).

I could not give you a worked sample, as I'm no MySQL expert: perhaps this will help you enough given the general nature of your question.

Comment: Yes I've seen this nesting fuction but my concept is not based on parent-child concept but rather on one level connected data.

Comment: Sorry, can't help you further. From first glance I'd say parent-child and one-level-connected are sufficiently similar that the technique can still be used - but I may be wrong.